# deleting an xml node

Tags: xml

i have an xml structure :

```
<xml>
<node label="comp_unit">
  <node label="stratum">
    <node label="tree"/>
     </node>
 </node>
 </xml>
```

now, i tried to delete the node with the stratum label = stratum,
so, i did this..
delete xml.node.(@label=="stratum");
but i got an error message: delete operator doesn't work on xmlList.
i tried this then:
delete XML(xml.node.(@label=="stratum");
but the node wasn't deleted..

any one has a clue?

Comment: Also you need to let us know what language it is you're using to work with the XML

Comment: am working with flex. thanks guys, i will improve on it from now on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
delete xml..node.(@label=="stratum")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the delete syntax you need, but you should use a single `=` for equal comparison in xpath: `@label="stratum"`

EDIT

You are right. Its not really XPath that is used in flex.

Maybe you need to retrieve the node list first and then delete the elements:

```
var nodeList:XMLList = xml..node.(@label=="stratum");
for(var i:int = nodeList.length() -1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    delete nodeList[i];
}
```

See [here](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?t=266128).

Comment: @morja, i am not fully sure but i will check that out and let you know. thanks

Comment: @morja, i have researched it and i am positive it should be @label=="stratum" in flex4 applications.

Comment: @morja, ok thanks alot..is it possible to accept two correct answers ? :)